# Merge into table with composite primary key

Tags: oracle, sql-merge

I'm trying to insert some entries into my table and do nothing when the entry already exists. My primary key consists of more than one column (event_timestamp, device_id, path, message_id).

When I try something like following statement in JDBC:

```
MERGE INTO events dest
                    USING ( SELECT event_timestamp, device_id, path, message_id from events) src
                    ON (dest.event_timestamp = src.event_timestamp
                    and dest.device_id = src.device_id
                    and dest.path = src.path
                    and dest.message_id = src.message_id)
                    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                    INSERT (event_timestamp, device_id, path, message_id, text, direction, speed, net, gross)
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Nothing gets inserted.

With a normal statement like :

```
INSERT (event_timestamp, device_id, path, message_id, text, direction, speed, net, gross) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

everything is inserted without problems.

I also tried changing the select statement to select from `DUAL` instead of events like :

```
MERGE INTO events dest
                    "USING ( SELECT event_timestamp, device_id, path, message_id from DUAL) src
                    ON (dest.event_timestamp = src.event_timestamp
                    and dest.device_id = src.device_id 
                    and dest.path = src.path
                    and dest.message_id = src.message_id)
                    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                    INSERT (event_timestamp, device_id, path, message_id, text, direction, speed, net, gross)
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

But then I get the exception: `ORA-00904: invalid identifier`

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: `WHEN MATCHED THEN` try doing an `UPDATE`, this will ensure matching records do exist or not

Comment: Is `event_timestamp` is a date or timestamp column? If so ensure to insert unique records.

Comment: @Jåcob: Thanks for commenting. I get following exception when I try to do an update on any of the referenced columns `ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated`. `event_timestamp` is a timestamp column. I'm trying to ensure I'm inserting unique records by checking the composite (event_timestamp, device_id, path, message_id).

Comment: It would be easier to understand your SQL if you posted "plain" SQL rather than String concatenation in Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new values you want to pass should be part of `SELECT FROM dual` in the `USING` clause

```
MERGE INTO events dest USING (
     SELECT ? as event_timestamp,
            ? as device_id,
            ? as path,
            ? as message_id
     FROM dual
)
src ON (
      dest.event_timestamp = src.event_timestamp 
      AND dest.device_id = src.device_id 
      AND dest.path = src.path 
      AND dest.message_id = src.message_id
)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
     event_timestamp,
     device_id,
     path,
     message_id,
     text,
     direction,
     speed,
     net,
     gross ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

A plain `INSERT INTO .. SELECT` like this can also be used.

```
INSERT INTO events (
     event_timestamp,
     device_id,
     path,
     message_id,
     text,
     direction,
     speed,
     net,
     gross ) 
SELECT ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( select 1 from events d WHERE  
          d.event_timestamp  = ? 
      AND d.device_id        = ?
      AND d.path             = ?
      AND d.message_id       = ?
      );
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3bf113a570c16c592e080b11daaa2f79)